# How can I get the default maximumTrackTintColor for a UISlider

Tags: ios, swift, uikit, uislider, tint

I'm trying to make a UISlider have the tint colour on the right side and the dull colour on the  left side (swap them around)

I'm able to get the correct colour on the right with

```
mySlider.maximumTrackTintColor = self.view.tintColor
```

but I don't know how to get the grey colour in order to set the `minimumTrackTintColor`.

I tried

```
mySlider.minimumTrackTintColor = mySlider.maximumTrackTintColor
```

before I set the `maximumTrackTintColor` but that doesn't work because `mySlider.maximumTrackTintColor` returns nil if a custom colour hasn't been set.

Comment: I know I can do `UIColor.lightGrayColor()`, but the default colour may change in a future version of iOS so I want to programatically find out what is used in the UISlider.

Comment: Do you want to change the saturation of the color?

Comment: @LeonardoSavioDabus By default the track to the left of the thumb is blue and to the right is grey. I want to the left of the thumb to be grey and to the right to be grey. But I don't want to just set it to be grey; I want to find out what colours are used by the UISlider and swap them.

Comment: I know it's dumb, but maybe you could just rotate the control 180 degrees and normalise the value in delegate callback?

Comment: @siejkowski I thought about that, but if they set any drop shadow or similar effect in the future, it will look odd.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ok, so the problem is that you are trying to get the tintColor, but the default vanilla iOS8 non-customised UISlider is not using tintColor to set its colors.

**It's using imageForState.**

So you can get the images with `slider.minimumTrackImageForState(UIControlState.Normal)!` and `slider.maximumTrackImageForState(UIControlState.Normal)!` methods.

However, to be more defensive I'd recommend trying both approaches:

```
let minimumColor = slider.minimumTrackTintColor
let maximumColor = slider.maximumTrackTintColor
let minimumImage = slider.minimumTrackImageForState(UIControlState.Normal)
let maximumImage = slider.maximumTrackImageForState(UIControlState.Normal)

if let minimumColor = minimumColor {
    slider.maximumTrackTintColor = minimumColor
} else if let minimumImage = minimumImage {
    slider.setMaximumTrackImage(minimumImage, forState: .Normal)
} else {
    // ok, something has changed the big way, just fallback on some color you like
}

if let maximumColor = maximumColor {
    slider.minimumTrackTintColor = maximumColor
} else if let maximumImage = maximumImage {
    slider.setMinimumTrackImage(maximumImage, forState: .Normal)
} else {
    // ok, something has changed the big way, just fallback on some color you like
}
```

The result is (top image before, down image after):

[image]

Comment: Well spotted that it's using images, not tint. But your code just seems to make the tracks thicker, it doesn't swap the colours

Comment: @Grezzo Could you please provide some more information? I've updated the answer with the result I get, and is seems that it does swap colors and don't make tracks thicker. What is your code? What are you seeing after setting proper images for states?

Comment: I used your code, but changed `slider` to my slider IBOutlet (called `rightSlider`). I logged the minimum/maximumColor/Image and all were `nil`. I changed the "something has changed" comment to a logged string and and that ended up being logged.

Comment: I made simple a project using your code (that doesn't work for me) and stuck it up on GitHub: https://github.com/Grezzo/SliderSwap

Comment: @Grezzo Thanks a lot! It seems that for whatever reason `slider` do not have the images set before it's shown on the screen. Moving the code to `viewDidAppear` let all the values be reported correctly. I genuinely have no idea why is that a case - it's probably an implementation detail of `UISlider` class.

Comment: I see. It's a shame that this can't be done before the view has appeared, but I guess it makes sense that it hasn't loaded the images by then. Thanks for your help!